# JPA merge of a children tree structure

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity that includes a number of OneToMany relationships to other entities. One of those entities is actually a tree structure (with three levels).

When I update my object (in a servlet call), I update all the object fields, including the tree structure, but only at the root level (first level). Once updated I do a merge of the object.

It works fine although kind of slow. I set the JPA logging to view the actual sql transactions being performed and noticed that the tree structure was always completely re generated in the database (ie delete and inserts of all objects). It is not the case for the other fields, ie only the ones that have changed are updated. It is as if eclipselink (I use eclipselink) viewed the tree structure as new each time.

Is this normal behaviour? do I need to scan down the tree and update each tree node before merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the id of the tree structure (include the code)?

Are you assign a new id, or making the id null before each merge?

Are you using orphanRemoval?

It is most an issue with how you are merging the changes (include the code).

Comment: Yes, indeed it was an id issue, nothing more. I was blinded because some ids were being refreshed and others not. It works as expected now. Thanks.